# How to remove all elements of an object by the keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, filter, key

I am just trying to figure out what is the best way to delete all elements of an object by doing an onClick function. The idea is that the handler should delete all elements. I have tried several options including using the delete keyword, and filtering. However, when I click the clear all button, it doesnt delete anything. Please see below for the code. Thank

And here is the console log of the object keys:

Comment: Need information about `itemConfigs`

Comment: filteredStoppedItems is, as you know, an array. You can use splice, but not delete, although the best way in this case is just to create an empty array.

Comment: @ Yossi , You can delete an item in an array, But it isn't that common, because Its same as `array[index] = undefiend`

Comment: `delete filteredStoppedItems[index]`where index should be 0..3, But you pass index: 16,14,11,8 Which doesn't exist...

Comment: Opps, totally forgot to include the image for itemConfigs. I have updated the post to show it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) to create a new object

```js
import omit from 'lodash/omit';

const itemConfigs = [{
    mode: 1,
    status: "STOPPED",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    mode: 1,
    status: "COMPLETED",
    value: 11
  },
  {
    mode: 1,
    status: "PENDING",
    value: 13
  },
  {
    mode: 1,
    status: "STOPPED",
    value: 12
  }
];

const filteredStoppedItems = Object.keys(itemConfigs).filter(
  (key) =>
  (itemConfigs[key].status === "STOPPED" ||
    itemConfigs[key].status === "COMPLETED" ||
    itemConfigs[key].status === "FAILED") &&
  itemConfigs[key].mode !== null
);

console.log("FILTEREDSTOPPEDITEMS", filteredStoppedItems);

console.log(omit(itemConfigs, filteredStoppedItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to delete all elements with a `forEach`, just assign it a new empty object;

```js
let obj = {
  happy: 0.6,
  neutral: 0.1,
  said: 0.3,
};

console.log(obj);

obj = {};

console.log(obj);
```